# How to use "OnPropertyChanged" on array

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make an Weather App as my first project in c#/WPF.
I am literally lost and cant find what I am doing wrong.

Here is my variable string array `weatherWeek` that I wanna fill with temperatures for next 7 days.

```cs
private string[] _weatherWeek = new string[7];
public string[] weatherWeek
{
     get
     {
          return _weatherWeek;
     }
     set
     {
          _weatherWeek = value;
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(weatherWeek));
     }
}
```

Here is my code I use for getting temperature for next 7 days.
When I use `Debu.WriteLine(Weather[0]);` I can see that data is there.

```cs
public async Task GetWeatherTempWeek()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
     {
          JObject jObjectWeek = JObject.Parse(jsonDataWeek);
          weatherWeek[i] = (string)jObjectWeek["days"][i]["temp"] + "°C";
     }
}
```

Here part of my XAML code where I binded weatherWeek variable.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding weatherWeek[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     Height="68"
     Width="68"
     FontSize="30"
     FontWeight="Bold"
     FontFamily="Tunga"
     TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Honestly I don't even remember everything I tried. Problem is that it works for normal variable but not for variable with array.

Comment: Changing the _array_ is not the same as changing an item _in the array_. If you want this to work, either replace the whole array in one go: `weatherWeek = JObject.Parse(jsonDataWeek)["days"].Take(7).Select(day => day["temp'] + "°C").ToArray();` *OR* use an observable collection ( a collection that notifies observers when elements are added, removed, and replaced)

Comment: You need to debug your code. You should have already done that before posting here. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn, because it is an essential skill. If you put breakpoints on your property getter and setter, you would see that it is actually the getter you're executing there and not the setter. At no point do you assign a `string` array to the property. What you're doing is getting the current array from the property, then setting an element of that existing array. Think putting an egg in an existing carton rather than replacing that carton with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(weatherWeek));` which is responsible for notifying the UI, as a workaround you can simply call it after you make change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        JObject jObjectWeek = JObject.Parse(jsonDataWeek);
        weatherWeek[i] = (string)jObjectWeek["days"][i]["temp"] + "°C";
    }
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(weatherWeek));
```

Answer (score 0):

To notify a collection change, the collection must implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. In a regular array, this interface is not implemented.
Most likely one of these solutions will work for you.
**1) Replacing the entire array.**

```cs
    public async Task GetWeatherTempWeek()
    {
            weatherWeek = JObject.Parse(jsonDataWeek)["days"]
                .Select(day => $"{day["temp"]}°C")
                .ToArray();
    }
```

**2) If you need an element-by-element replacement function in a collection, then the array should be changed to ObservableCollection**

```cs
    public ObservableCollection<string> weatherWeek { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty,7));
```

```cs
    public async Task GetWeatherTempWeek()
    {
        var days = JObject.Parse(jsonDataWeek)["days"]; ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            weatherWeek[i] = (string)days["temp"] + "°C";
        }
    }
```